# How can I enumerate a local directory in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am aware that browsers have necessary limitations making web pages agnostic of the local file tree. I am hosting a web-served page within a desktop application and this new feature requires that I display a list of local directories.

1) Is there a way I can do this directly within the page itself. (I doubt it.)

2) Is there a way I can communicate with the desktop application that is hosting me.

What makes things more difficult is that this application is written in MFC. I'm hitting up against security constraints and I don't know what to do.

Comment: That really depends on the API the desktop application is providing to the page.

Comment: If you're trying to communicate with an application you control the installation of, would it be possible to require IIS (assumption: this is a Windows application, otherwise, replace with Apache or whatever else) as a prereq for your application? Then you could install a web service for the javascript to communicate with, which could return anything you wanted it to. Probably other ways too, that's just my first thought. Simplest on the javascript end, just more complexity on the other end

Comment: The closest to that might be http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: @neminem, all of this is happening on the client. The information I need is on the client. I should have made that clear.

Comment: @SebastianNette, to my knowledge MFC can only use Internet Explorer.

Comment: @FelixKling, my question is how do I even provide an API, any API, to a served page? To my knowledge a served page cannot interact with the client at all.  In my case the client is an MFC application which limits communication even farther. I'm thinking this is impossible.

Comment: Right - which is why I was suggesting that your client program, itself, could install an IIS component to communicate with ;)
. Totally hacky, but it'd work (assuming your target environment is such that your users would be willing to do that/have that done.)

Comment: As this a relatively small feature on an existing distributed application, I'm going with extremely hacky. Yes. If it were a .NET application I could incorporate an HTTP listener. It is MFC. What I'll probably have to do is have the MFC client download static, standalone pages and then communicate with them via `CHtmlView::OnTitleChanged`. I am not looking forward to this.